# Intercepting asp.net ajax webmethod

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Is there a way to intercept asp.net ajax webmethods(aspx page static methods)?

i want to intercept before request reaching the method and also after sending the response.

Comment: What are you trying to do before and after?

Answer (score 1):

use in global.asax file

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //before method colling
        string ss = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();//use if it is equal to your page webmethod url  i.e. example.com/default.aspx/GetMessage;
        if(ss == "http://example.com/default.aspx/GetMessage")
        {
            // do your work here
        }
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //after method colling
        string ss = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();// use if  it is equal to your page webmethod i.e. example.com/default.aspx/GetMessage;

        if(ss=="http://example.com/default.aspx/GetMessage")
        {
            // do your work here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will help me but if i want to intercept every webmethod is there any way? because this solution i have to write many if else conditions. is there any way i can detect whether it is webmethod or normal page request?